# scalaz Free Monad control break and pause for a chain of computations

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz

I have a chain of computations which changes the state of Context:

```
case class Context(...)
type Step = (Context => Context)
val step1: Step = ctx => { ctx.copy(...) }
val step2: Step
val step3: Step
// ...
val stepN: Step
val chain = List(step1, step2, step3, ..., stepN).toStream
```

And I would like to introduce the return value of computation to control the flow of that chain:

```
trait Cont
case class Break[Context](ctx: Context) extends Cont
case class Pause[Context](ctx: Context) extends Cont
case class Continue[Context](ctx: Context) extends Cont
```

**Break** - means cancelling chain after executing current step,

**Pause** - means suspending computation on current step after executing it, with ability to resume the next step later (and check if it's resumable?)

**Continue** - means normal continuation of the flow.

Each step should return the current value of context wrapped in Cont.

Currently I'm doing that by unfolding the stream of steps (val chain: Stream[Cont[Step]]) and checking the chain.isEmpty and chain.head to check if there's some computation left.

How can I do that using Free monads in scalaz?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the continuation monad of scalaz, `scalaz.Cont`.

Sadly there is no documentation and there are no examples on how to use `scalaz.Cont`. So, to get a basic understanding of continuations and what they are for, have a look at

- [wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads#The_Continuation_monad](https://wiki.haskell.org/All_About_Monads#The_Continuation_monad) and at
- [en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Continuation_passing_style).
- For using the Free monad, a recommended reading is *Functional and Reactive Domain Modelling* by Debasish Ghosh.

The essence of using continuations is, that we will not return values from our computations but pass the control to a continuation (often the variable `k` is used) and the continuation specifies what happens next.

This said, let us look at how this would look like in your concrete example:

- first some type definitions ; notice that a `Continuation`, a "next step", is a function which takes a `Context` and returns something of type `Return`

  ```
  case class Context(i: Int)
  type Continuation = Context => Return
  ```
- then define some types to control the flow within our computation chain ; note that `Pause` also returns a `Continuation` since we want to be able to continue the computation later

  ```
  trait Return
  case class Break(context: Context) extends Return
  case class Pause(context: Context, continuation: Continuation) extends Return
  case class Done(context: Context) extends Return
  ```
- next we define our steps as classes in order to be able to use them with the Free monad ...

  ```
  trait Step[A]
  case class Step1(c: Context) extends Step[Context]
  case class Step2(c: Context) extends Step[Context]
  case class Step3(c: Context) extends Step[Context]
  ```
- ... and lift them into the context of the Free monad

  ```
  type Command[A] = Free[Step, A]
  protected implicit def liftStep[A](step: Step[A]): Command[A] =
      Free.liftF(step)

  def step1(c: Context): Command[Context] = Free.liftF(Step1(c))
  def step2(c: Context): Command[Context] = Free.liftF(Step2(c))
  def step3(c: Context): Command[Context] = Free.liftF(Step3(c))
  ```
- now we build our chain of computations ; note that we pass the result of the previous computation (e.g. `c1`) into the next (e.g. `step2(c1)`) ; if this should happen more implicitly, maybe the state monad should be considered for passing state from continuation to continuation

  ```
  val script = for {
    c0 <- Free.point(Context(0))
    c1 <- step1(c0)
    c2 <- step2(c1)
    c3 <- step3(c2)
  } yield c3
  ```
- and define an interpreter (i.e. `step`) which evaluates the single steps ; see the comments for an explanation of how the single steps can control the flow of the computation

  ```
  type Process[A] = Cont[Return, A]
  val step: Step ~> Process = new (Step ~> Process) {
    override def apply[A](action: Step[A]): Process[A] = action match {
      case Step1(c) =>
        Cont { k: Continuation =>
          // call next computation with context value set to 1
          k(c.copy(i = 1))
        }
      case Step2(c) =>
        Cont { k: Continuation =>
          // pause computation ; to be able to resume, continuation k is returned
          Pause(c.copy(i = 2), k)
        }
      case Step3(c) =>
        Cont { k: Continuation =>
          // after the pause, the computation is resumed here
          k(c.copy(i = 3))
          // alternatively: break computation (i.e. not resumable)
          //Break(c.copy(i = 3))
        }
    }
  }
  ```
- run the `script` with the interpreter `step` to get the continuation

  ```
  val process: Cont[Return, Context] = script.foldMap(step)
  ```
- run the continuation `process` ; note that the run method expects a `Continuation` which will be the continuation of the last computation step (i.e. `c` will be `Context(3)` from `Step3`)

  ```
  var result = process.run(c => Done(c))
  ```
- at last, write some code to execute the complete chain and continue if the computation was just paused or stop if `Break` or `Done` is the result

  ```
  var continue = true
  do {
    continue = result match {
      case Pause(c, continuation) =>
        println(s"Pause: $c")
        result = continuation(c)
        true
      case Break(c) =>
        println(s"Break: $c")
       false
      case Done(c) =>
        println(s"Done: $c")
       false
     }
  } while(continue)
  ```

The result is:

```
Pause: Context(2)
Done: Context(3)
```